# Getting JSON parsing error when sending JMeter Assertion result through email

Tags: groovy, jmeter, smtp, jsr223

In my JMeter test plan, I added below as JSR223 Assertion to format the JSON response.

```
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;

def failureMessage = "";
def jsonResponse = null;
def headers = null;
def responseTime = null;

JsonSlurper JSON = new JsonSlurper();
prev.setResponseData(groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(prev.getResponseDataAsString()))

try {
    jsonResponse = JSON.parseText(prev.getResponseDataAsString());
    log.info("Wards response: "+jsonResponse);
    headers = SampleResult.getRequestHeaders();
    responseTime = SampleResult.getTime();
   
} catch (Exception e) {
    failureMessage += "Invalid JSON.\n"
}
if (!"200".equals(prev.getResponseCode())) {
    failureMessage += "Expected <response code> [200] but we got instead [" + prev.getResponseCode() + "]\n\n";
}
if (!"OK".equals(prev.getResponseMessage())) {
    failureMessage += "Expected <response Message> [OK] but we got instead [" + prev.getResponseMessage() + "]\n\n";
}

if (!jsonResponse.keySet().containsAll(["wards"])) {
    failureMessage += "The json config element has wrong structure. No wards key\n\n";
}
if (!jsonResponse.wards.getAt(0).keySet().containsAll(["id","name","shortName"])) {
    failureMessage += "The wards element has wrong structure. Key(s) are missing or wrong \n\n";
}

if (!jsonResponse.wards.size==95) {
    failureMessage += "Wards count is wrong..! :[" + jsonResponse.wards.size + "]\n\n";
}
if (!(headers.contains("ticketheader") && headers.contains("Content-Type") && headers.contains("Host") && headers.contains("User-Agent"))) {
    failureMessage += "Headers are not correct..!";
}

if (failureMessage?.trim()) {
    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}

// Print error messages if any
if (failureMessage?.trim()) {
    failureMessage += "URL: " + SampleResult.getURL() + "\n\n";
    failureMessage += "JSON RESPONSE: " + jsonResponse + "\n\n";
    failureMessage += "REQUEST HEADERS: " + SampleResult.getRequestHeaders() + "\n\n";

    AssertionResult.setFailureMessage(failureMessage);
    AssertionResult.setFailure(true);
}
```

Then I added below Beanshell script to get the Assertion Test results thorough email body.

```
import org.apache.jmeter.assertions.AssertionResult;

AssertionResult[] results = prev.getAssertionResults();
StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder();
for (AssertionResult result : results) {
    body.append(result.getFailureMessage());
    body.append(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
}
vars.put("body", body.toString());
```

But in result email, I'm getting below error.

```
*javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.json.JsonException: Lexing failed on line: 1, column: 1, while reading 'j', no possible valid JSON value or punctuation could be recognized.*
```

In my test plan I need to use both scripts to format the JSON and send the email. How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: groovy.json.JsonException is the exception thrown by the JSON builder and slurper classes, whenever a problem occurs when creating or parsing JSON data structures. So, I believe you are passing not a json to json a slurper.

Answer (score 0):

Your script is failing because you're not getting valid JSON, proper JSON object starts with `{` or `[` and you're getting `j`, try using a service like [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) which will highlight all problematic places in your response

[Since JMeter 3.1 you should not be using Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so I believe you can put your Beanshell code to the [JSR223 Assertion](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/scripting-jmeter-assertions-in-groovy-a-tutorial), it will work without changes.

Comment: Now I'm getting below error in email body.                                                                                  javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method keySet() on null object